# Playing video in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a webview control in linear layout. I want to play html video in vebview control.
I am trying to display the video  the same as the screen when in portrait mode  and display it full screen when in landscape mode.

This is my xml layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myBrowser"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
     />

 </LinearLayout>
```

and you can find the screenshot about the problem below :
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to control the `webView`

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

and also add this code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Don't call `setContentView()` before `requestFeature()`.

Comment: I am getting following error : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Don't call setContentView() before requestFeature().

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify this in your HTML page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

And enable viewport on your WebView:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```